# ARR 3 IIS 7.5 Windows Authentication not working

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, iis-7.5, windows-authentication, arr

We have been spinning our wheels trying to get **windows authentication** working through **ARR**.

We've created a new domain account (`appservices`)

**ARR Server** (`srvarr`) using default app pool with user set to `appservices`

**IIS Server** (`srvweb`) using default app pool with user set to `appservices`

We've run

```
setspn -s domain\appservices http://srvarr
```

and checking using `-l` shows it registered for `http://srvarr`

`srvarr` is set to use `anonymous authentication`

`srvweb` is set to use `windows authentication`

Going directly to `http://srvweb/healthCheck.txt` gives a `'Working!'` message
Trying to go to `http://srvarr/healthCheck.txt` gives either a

```
502 - Web server received an invalid response while acting as a gateway or proxy server
```

or

```
401 - with prompt for credentials
```

If we turn on `anonymous authentication` we get the `'Working!'` message from either `http://srvweb/healthCheck.txt` or `http://srvarr/healthCheck.txt`

We've tried both **NTLM** and **Negotiate** and neither seem to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We had typo'd `HTTP/srvarr` and `HTTP/srvweb` as `http://srvarr` and `http://srvweb`. Make sure you do it as the protocol instead of the url!

Also settings that might help others:

**Remove** both `NTLM` and `Negotiate` and **add** `Negotiate:Kerberos` and turn **on** `UseAppPoolCredentials` and **off** `useKernelMode`

Make sure all of the servers are using your domain web service account as the app pool identity